# You have exceeded the number of permissible concurrent requests with unique IAM Identities. Please retry. Why this type of error comes?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, opensearch

I am trying to query AWS ElasticSearch with 100,000 requests per minute. But after few mins i am getting the error as "You have exceeded the number of permissible concurrent requests with unique IAM Identities. Please retry".

I have a lambda function which is querying ES.
Can i get the help that why we are receiving this error?

I have tried to debug AWS cloudwatch to check the reason, even contacted AWS support team. The AWS support team is saying that more than 1000 IAM users might be creating. But we are not doing anything as such.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9696#issuecomment-1038571225 might be helpful.